# How can I solve this issue on Mac M1 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64

Tags: java, android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I solved this issue with the code below in my build.gradle

```
  allprojects {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
      }
   }
 }
```

But it has an effect on the project I am working on. for some reason, it is not working with room sql implemented on the project.

I get this error when i removed the code above.

Is there a better approach to solve this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:82)
at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:57)
at androidx.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:134)
at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:161)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
... 39 more

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and 
os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:333)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:64)
at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier.<clinit>(DatabaseVerifier.kt:68)
... 47 more
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a third-party sqlite driver (which may not support Android). Please show all your gradle build dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update your room library

```
   implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
   implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
   kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```

Here is [Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_2)

Answer (score 1):

In my case updating to `2.4.2` only asking me to update the SDK version to 31 and more problem appears. I found alternative solution by selecting

`Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`

Navigate to **Gradle Project section** and click **Gradle JDK dropdown option field**.

[image: illustration]

Select Liberica-1.8 (if it is not available in dropdown field, you can download and install here https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/).

Run the project again and voila!!

Answer (score 0):

yeb run working on my case(my mac mini m1)
=>>>
`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2" implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

update your roomdb dependencies

```
def room_version = "2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mac M1 :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```